# SQL count and filter query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

Given a database table `article_bookmarks` with columns `userId` and `articleId`, if a user bookmarks an article a table entry (`userId`, `articleId`) with respective ids is made.

I want to retrieve the total number of users that bookmarked a specific article given by `articleId`, together with the info if the user (given by `userId`) also bookmarked that article.

My SQL query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ar.userId) AS bookmark_count,
       EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM article_bookmarks WHERE articleId=:articleId AND userId=:userId) AS user_bookmarked
FROM article_bookmarks ar
WHERE ar.articleId=:articleId
```

I have the impression that this query is not optimal, as it seems inefficient and redundant to read out basically the same `userId` data twice: One time aggregated in a "count", the other time filtered by a single `userId` with a sub-select.

Is there a way to optimize or simplify the given SQL query (i.e. something like `SELECT COUNT(ar.userId) AS bookmark_count, EXISTS(:userId IN ar.userId) AS user_bookmarked` [...] in valid SQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. Here the table `article_bookmarks` is scanned only once.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ar.userId) AS bookmark_count,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userId=:userId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS user_bookmarked
FROM article_bookmarks ar
WHERE ar.articleId=:articleId
```

To avoid scanning the whole table you need an index on `(articleId, userId)` or `(articleId) include (userId)`.

Comment: Alternatively: `count(*) filter (where userid = :userId) > 0 as user_bookmarked`